# Delete a file after downloading attachment

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to create a macro to download attachments from email I recieve and THEN delete the email.

I've got the macro to download the attachment, however, I don't know how to make it delete the email AFTER it downloads. When I use a rule, it deletes the email BEFORE downloading the attachment.

Here's what I've got:

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim sSaveFolder As String
sSaveFolder = "S:\Training and Curriculum\Staff Training Files\01 scans\"
For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Just use `MItem.Delete`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell on that sub, you are passing MItem as the Outlook.MailItem object, which if I read your question correctly, is the item you want deleted.  After your `next` in your loop, you should just be able to do MItem.Delete, which will delete that particular item after saving the file.

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim sSaveFolder As String
sSaveFolder = "S:\Training and Curriculum\Staff Training Files\01 scans\"

For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
    oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
Next

MItem.Delete 'This is the delete command

End Sub
```

Here is the MSDN documentation on `MailItem.Delete` - [MSDN MailItem Delete Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/mailitem-delete-method-outlook)